# Fetching the address of web server dynamically using JS

Tags: javascript, url, web

I have an Angular JS app, wherein the back end is built in .NET. To fetch the data I call the exposed API controller methods from .NET project.

While calling the controller methods, I need to add "http://localhost:port" at the starting of controller method path. So my complete URL is something like:

`http://localhost:port/api/controller/method`

This seems obvious to me. However, while migrating this app to higher environments, I manually need to replace this string with the IPs of environment server. SO that same URL on PROD becomes:

`http://PROD-IP:port/api/controller/method`

Although this too makes sense, my queries are as below:

1. Should not localhost point to the server automatically. I mean if I deploy my app on 127.0.0.1 on every environment, then localhost:port should work fine in each case, and I need not to replace the IP for each environment. (This is my opinion and this approach is not currently working)
2. Is there a way in JS to fetch the IP address from the current URL. So that, a user enters the app URL at beginning and later for all back end call, I get the server URL. I tried `document.location` but it didn't work as expected.

I tried looking for solutions on various blog, but probably I couldn't frame correct words and didn't get any relevant solution.

Comment: `document.location.origin` should work if your app is served by the same server which provides the api

Comment: thanx: That provides the required help

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have any concept of hostnames or IP addresses. You would have to use an external service to resolve an IP address from a hostname.
You can get the domainname using `location.hostname` and then use some external webservices to lookup its `IP`